# Ubuntu 19.10, dual monitor: GNOME Activities overview messed up

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, activities-overview, 19.10

Please see these two screenshots,

one with no windows:
[image]
(click to enlarge)

and one with multiple windows:
[image]
(click to enlarge)

In each one, the GNOME search bar is covered up, and the desktops are hidden from view. Is there a way to fix this?

I would like there to be a search bar in the top middle of each monitor, just like Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by configuring this setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter workspaces-only-on-primary true
```

I also installed dash-to-dock gnome extension, but I'm unsure if that helped.

Here are some screenshots of it fixed.
no windows:
[image: no windows]

extra windows:
[image: extra windows]