# Activities-overview's section of primary monitor bleeds into section of second monitor

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, activities-overview

I have a dual monitor setup and when I click the activities-overview, the area meant to be displayed on my primary display bleeds into the section for the second monitor.
If I set my secondary monitor as my "primary display" in setting, the behavior is as expected.

This odd behavior started about 5 months after I installed Ubuntu 18.04. I currently upgraded to 19.10 and the problem still persists.

I tried the solution outlined [Ubuntu 19.10, dual monitor: GNOME Activities overview messed up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182937/ubuntu-19-10-dual-monitor-gnome-activities-overview-messed-up) with no success.

See the screenshots below.

[image]

Below is another screenshot of another workspace.

[image]